# I am trying to install Node.Js but it keeps showing me this. what can I do to solve this problem?

Tags: node.js

[this is the error message I get trying to install Node.js on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy1Z6.jpg)

Comment: Hello, do you have logs or details? There's not really anything to go off of on the screenshot you posted

Comment: No, I don't, I just clicked the Node.js Package I downloaded and it show's me that on the screenshot.. been stuck for days now I don't know what to do

Comment: Perhaps a permission issue.

Comment: so how do I go about it?

Comment: I've found CLI utilities are usually much more reliable and provide better traces. Try installing Node using NVS: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `NodeJS` on `Windows` you need to have a minimum of `10 GB` free disk space in the `C:\\` drive. From your above error picture I see you are getting a not enough disk space error. So you have to free up some space on the `C:\\` drive. And if you still get error when you have enough space then you have to run the installation script as administrator.

Comment: Tried this and it worked like a charm, I install Node js as a admin. thanks mate.

Comment: @codestitches Great to hear about that. If this answer helped you, hopefully, you will accept the answer and mark this answer as an answer so the people who are facing this same problem and also people who will face the same problem will get benefited from the answer :) –

Answer (score 0):

Right click Start button > File Explorer > Select This PC in left column and check C:\ drive in right hand column.

How much free space do you have on the C:\ drive?

Comment: I have 235 GB free space on my C:\ drive

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).